# can gmock mock overloaded methods?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I just started to do testing with gtest and gmock, then I am stopped by a problem. The problem is like this,

First, I have a class like this,

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<int>& GetVec() { return m_MyVec; }
    const std::vector<int>& GetVec() const { return m_MyVec; }
private:
    std::vector<int> m_MyVec;
};
```

then I would like to setup mock on overloaded functions,

```
class MockFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    MockFoo() {};
protected:
    MOCK_METHOD0(GetVec, std::vector<int>&()); // This is fine
    MOCK_METHOD0(GetVec, const std::vector<int>&() const); // This not good
}
```

The error message from Visual Studio 2013 is this:
imcomplete type is not allowed.

Could any body tell me if it is possible to mock overloaded methods, if the answer is YES, then how? Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error on the line where you define the mocked const method, which is always done with `MOCK_CONST_METHODX` macro.

```
MOCK_METHOD0(GetVec, const std::vector<int>&() const); // This not good
```

Should be:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetVec, const std::vector<int>&()); // This should be ok
```